# TrueCrypt AutoMount With Key

Tags: autohotkey

MountTC:

```
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%\TrueCrypt\
Run, %comspec% /c TrueCrypt.exe /q /volume "\Device\%EncryptedPartition%" /k "Key.tc" /e /b,Hide
```

Whenever I run this command the drive does not mount. TrueCrypt runs but it doesnt do much after that. I am not sure what I did wrong.

Could someone help  me get it to mount correctly.

Comment: Remove the "hide" and change /c to /k to inspect if there are any errors.

Comment: If you really need the command prompt, you probably should wrap a lot of that in "quotes".   i.e. /c "truecrypt.exe /q ... /e /b"   But try just running truecrypt /q ...